# Failed to open VM session

Tags: virtualbox

Cannot start VM session. The error received is:

> The device helper structure version has changed.
>
> If you have upgraded Virtualbox recently, please make sure you have
> terminated all Vms and upgraded any extension packs. If this error
> persists, try reinstalling VirtualBox.

I've tried renaming Vbox files, creating a new VM session, updating to VBox 5.2.4, and updating DPKG files.  The error persists whenever I try to open a session.

Any advice?

Comment: This might be the worst choice, but try to backup your VMs first, then purge the entire VirtualBox packages before reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks Aryo, However, nothing has changed as a result. Still get the same error when trying to load.

Comment: Something has changed recently and it's not clear what it is. VirtualBox no longer works on any of my Linux machines for some reason and I get a similar error.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and VirtualBox are you using?